# how to get the homescreen?

Tags: blackberry

Hi  I am new to Blackberry and I am developing a application with reference to Library project.When I run the project with reference to the library one it is successfully compile the application..But when I clean the smulator and workspace and and run the app then the it is showing the app icon on the simulator but it is not going to the application. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: So when you click on the app icon, the app does not launch?

Comment: Yes it is not launching the app.I will make it clear.When I commented some part of the code I am able to launch the app.But when I removed the comments and check I am not able to launch it.I am using the following code snippnet.
PersistentObject pQues   = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(0xbd7460a5b4f9890aL);
 String stored_value = (String) pQues.getContents(); 
  /*int k=Integer.parseInt(stored_value);
          System.out.println("K Value is " +k); 
  if(k==1)
  {    
  pushScreen(new HomeScreen());
  }
  else { 
   pushScreen(new HomeScreen1());
  } */
  pushScreen(new HomeScreen());
 }

Answer (score 0):

Per the answer above - take a look in BB event log, I suspect you'll find an exception there with a rough stack trace that should give you a starting point.

To get to the event log , from the Home screen type ALT L ALT G ALT L ALT G